# SQL Server : try catch or @@error get more efficient

Tags: sql-server

I had two SQL commands which both work fine for me.

This is the first one:

```
DECLARE @SeqID  int,
    @RtnCode    int     
BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION    
       INSERT INTO TableA (Name,Value) 
       VALUES (@Name,@Value)        

       SET @SeqID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()        

       Insert Into TableB(TableASeqID, Name, Vlaue) 
       Values (@SeqID, @Name, @Value)               

   COMMIT TRANSACTION   

   SET @RtnCode = '1'
   GOTO FINALMSG    
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH  
   IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 BEGIN
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION     
       SET @RtnCode = '10001'
       GOTO FINALMSG
   END
END CATCH
FINALMSG:
BEGIN           
    SELECT
        @RtnCode
END
```

This is the second one:

```
DECLARE @SeqID  int,
        @RtnCode    int     
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO TableA (Name, Value) 
    VALUES (@Name, @Value)  

    IF(@@ERROR <> 0 OR @@ROWCOUNT <> 1)
    BEGIN                           
        ROLLBACK TRAN   
        SET @RtnCode = '1001'
        GOTO FINALMSG           
    END 

    SET @SeqID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()   

    Insert Into TableB(TableASeqID, Name, Vlaue) 
    Values (@SeqID, @Name, @Value)  

    IF(@@ERROR <> 0 OR @@ROWCOUNT <> 1)
    BEGIN                           
        ROLLBACK TRAN   
        SET @RtnCode = '1001'
        GOTO FINALMSG           
    END 

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    SET @RtnCode = '1'
    GOTO FINALMSG

FINALMSG:
    BEGIN           
        SELECT
            @RtnCode
    END
```

The first command usually use on my work, but DBA likes the second one.

I get confused with this.

Which way is the better way withing efficient?

Is Try Catch are more consumption effectiveness than every command use `@@ERROR()`?

Comment: TRY/CATCH is the more modern and simpler way for you as a programmer - the checking of `@@ERROR` is the old-fashioned, well-tested version that many DBA's prefer (because they tend to be conservative, often don't like new ways of doing things). Personally: I would always prefer `TRY / CATCH` since it makes the code much cleaner and simpler - you can save yourself having to check `@@ERROR` every second or third line in your code ....

Comment: Agree with @marc_s, TRY/CATCH is preferable for code readability. Impact on performance will be very minimal, if there is a difference it will be marginal compared to time spent in queries.

Answer (score 0):

I could not come up with a reason to use `@@RAISEERROR` instead of `TRY-CATCH` - I don't think `TRY-CATCH` will perform better/worse than `@@RAISEERROR`.

- with `TRY-CATCH` readability is lot better thereby it is easy to
  maintain or make changes - one example from your code is - you dont need to have the `FINALMSG` block and `GOTO` statements in your first set of statements using `TRY-CATCH`
- can use features like `THROW` instead of dealing with `@@RAISEERROR` and its
  parameters

[This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20002.structured-error-handling-mechanism-in-sql-server-2012.aspx#What_are_the_benefits_of_THROW_when_we_have_RAISERROR) article has more details on `TRY-CATCH-THROW` and their benefits.